# Let block not working, giving "Only safe (?.)..." error

Tags: android, kotlin, let

My `parent` variable is `nullable`, and haves a `getWidth` function. I want to call `getWidth` only if parent is not null, so I did this `let` function:

```
return parent.let {
    it.getWidth() * (perWidth / 100.0f)
} ?: run{
    App.realWidth.toFloat()
}
```

Also, if is null, I want to call `App.realWidth.toFloat()`, so I added it in a `?: run` which I read is like doing an `else` in a `let` function.

The problem is that it is giving me this error on `it.getWidth()`

> Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a
> nullable receiver of type ParentInterface?

I don't understand why, because it can't be null, as it is inside a `let` block.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write it as

```
return parent?.let {
```

Otherwise it still comes in the `let` block when it's null, with `it` being null

Comment: thank you, and why kotlin lets you doing let without ?, does it have any sense to do it without ?

Comment: @NullPointerException I'm not sure what use cases it would have. Could maybe just be to avoid having to write the variable name all the time and just use `it` in case you use `it` a lot in that block

Comment: can't believe someone has voted negatively my question, btw, thank you for your help

Comment: @NullPointerException for the record, it wasn't me that downvoted

Comment: I know, don't worry

Comment: Personally, I far prefer `.let { if (it != null) something else someFallback }` to `?.let { something } ?: someFallback`, especially for when you aren't trying to return the result. With the first, you could inadvertently run both the lambda and the fallback expression if you didn't account for the possibility of the `let` lambda resolving to null. Also, chained scope functions are just hard to read. So there are some reasons for allowing it.

Comment: `let` can also be used for code scoping purposes. Kotlin doesn't allow arbitrary `{ }` blocks for code scoping like Java does--you have to use scope functions for that. You may or may not want the subject to be nullable inside.